# spring data jpa + unwanted unique key generation

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa for creation of my tables.  My Requirement.

I have two Tables.
Basket Table -  It has one to many Relationship with the Item table. A basket can have many Items.

Item Table - Here an Item can be associated with many Baskets.

I am using IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX to make sure that the same combination of basketId and itemId, does not get persisted

So there is a mapping table in between in which holds the mapping of baskets and items. Now, in this table, i want the combination of basketId and itemId to be unique. Below is my entity stucture.

```
@Entity
Class Basket{

@Id
private long basketId;
...

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.Merge, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(
name= "mapping_table",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ='basketId'),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ='itemId'),
indexes = {@Index(name = "my_index", columnList = "basketId, itemId", unique = true)}
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT /*+ IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX (mapping_table, my_index) */ INTO mapping_table(basketId, itemId) values (?,?)")
private List<Item> itemList;

...

}


@Entity
Class Item{

@Id
private long itemId;

}
```

my_index with the combination of both the keys are getting created, as expected in the mapping_table

Problem 1:
In the mapping_table, for some wierd reason,  a new unique constraint with only itemId is created. Due to this unique key constraint, i am not able to persist rows where an item is associated with multiple  baskets. As i said, i want the combination of both the keys to be unique and i am achieving this by creating the index (my_index)

Problem 2:
Why is basketId (which is also Identifier) in the basketTable not marked as unique in the mapping table. This not a problem but more of a question. Becuase itemId which is identifier in the item table has unique key constraint in the mapping table.

Solution :
I create the tables using spring data jpa, login to the db manually and drop the unique key constraint and the persist. But this is not possible in Production

**Question**

I want to do alter table to drop the constraint first before the persist thing happens. **How to do that.**

P.S, As you can see, I have imagined these tables and have not put the names of the actual table. Not withstanding the made up table names, the problem statement is accurate. I am using Oracle as target DB

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a Set instead of a List, JPA should generated the correct schema with the correct constraints.

Comment: I tried with Set. But the result is same. It creates Unique key constraint on itemId but not on basketId.

Is there a way i can run the alter table commands post creation / update of tables from spring.

Comment: May be a problem with the provider you are using... Hibernate, EclipseLink? which version ?

Comment: Am using Hibernate